# memory limit exhausted flysystem/src/Util/MimeType.php, how to find path to file?

Tags: php, laravel, flysystem

I started to receive this error in my Laravel log
Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 227371200 bytes)

Is there is any way to get more information on what script / file being attempted to manipulate? I looked for similar size file on server and I couldn't find anything.

My first call was that maybe it's some log file that got too big.

Upping memory limit to 2GB solved the problem partially, but my worry is that this quick fix is not solving actual issue as I have no clue what file is being attempted to change or why script needs so much memory.

From what I can tell it happens when one of my /api function being called.

If it was infinite loop I assume upping the limit would not help.

````
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
    "message": "Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 227371200 bytes)",
    "code": 1,
    "file": "\/vendor\/league\/flysystem\/src\/Util\/MimeType.php:188"
}```
````

Comment: Am assuming this is something related to file upload, it would be great to have the full call stack of the log file, the information you provided so far isn't helpful

Comment: @CaddyDZ that's the problem, this is all I get in error log, I want to get more information, but it's all that comes through

Answer (score 2):

You can handle files as streams to prevent memory issues with large files.

See `Storage::putFile()` [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#storing-files) or use PHPs `fopen()` to get a stream handle you can pass to Laravels storage methods.

Comment: the main problem is that I can't find out what file is being attempted to manipulate that requires so much memory.

Comment: Then you have to check every step your application takes when accessing a route that triggers this error. Somewhere [MimeType](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/blob/master/src/Util/MimeType.php#L188) tries to guess the mime-type of a very large file...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a known bug in PHP - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78987
which is caused by an upstream bug in libmagic - https://bugs.astron.com/view.php?id=234